# Extend colors of header to screen edge using Drupal zen theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-zen

How can I easily apply a bg image to only the gutter space between my header and the screen edge, using the zen theme? I am also interested in doing this for the footer as well.

Answer (score 0):

faced this creating this zen subtheme: http://mb.petrmarek.eu/

header: make a bg img for body

footer: easily define a custom region under the page wrapper and make a custom block for the footer